# best way to close hosted process

Tags: c#, process, .net-3.5, kill

I have process A that starts process B.
they communicate in WCF (IAsyncResult APM Pattern), A is client B is service.
When Process A dies, i need to close B.

I am sending process A id as arg to process b and he does:

```
Process.GetProcessById(processId).WaitForExit();
```

This is working fine.
My question is how to kill process b properly if process a dies ?

I tried all the following:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().Close();
Process.GetCurrentProcess().Dispose();
Application.Exit(); > its a guiless winform application
```

The only thing that worked was:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

But isnt killing the process is too brutal ?

Adding code:
Process B inside main:

```
TrackExternalProcess(externalProcessId, () => { OnExternalProcessClosed(); });
```

Public methods:

```
    public static void TrackExternalProcess(int processId, Action onExternalProcessClosed)
    {
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
                Process.GetProcessById(processId).WaitForExit();

                logger.Error("Host process quit unexpectedly");

                onExternalProcessClosed();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        })).Start();
    }

    public static void OnExternalProcessClosed()
    {
        Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();

    }
```

Comment: What happens if in B, you don't try and do anything - and instead just do `Application.Start();`, does it then terminate by itself if A is terminated?

Comment: there is no Application.Start().

Comment: Using Kill() is fine and not too brutal as you have put it. I would create an event handler for process A to know when it is closed or aborted: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @PmanAce Cross-process event?

Comment: Have you considered having process B poll process A instead of A having to indicate a failure?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @DavinTryon i cant. Process A is main core sdk and process B is one of many APIs main SDK will open a new process for. A consume information from it (B), so when main process dies, i would like to kill all the others.

Comment: @Ilansch - my bad, I meant `Application.Run()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no cleaner version, I simply called my Dispose method.
It took care for everything, e.g closed WCF services.
And finally Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();

Answer (score 2):

Isn't `Environment.Exit()` cleaner ?

Comment: Thank you. this might be useful for further development